# ColdFusion occasionally returns just a hash symbol (#)

Tags: coldfusion

We have one page that for just one user is occasionally returning nothing but a hash symbol (#).  This page works perfectly fine for other users all of the time, and perfectly fine for this user much of the time.  We cannot reproduce the problem internally.  Unfortunately, this problem is sporadic and occurs within a modal dialog, so we cannot really test outside the modal dialog and we cannot get the html source when it does occur.

I recall running into a similar problem once before.  Some random page was returning just a pound sign.  Being able to see what was actually going on since it wasn't in a modal dialog, and having it occur in a dev environment, I resolved it pretty quickly then.  But it was a while ago and I can't recall any details of the incident.  Has anyone else ever seen CF do this before?  Any thoughts on what might cause it?

Comment: I just received word that this has happenned to other users on this page as well.  We only ever noticed it for the one person because he uses the page much more often than everyone else put together.

Comment: This is occuring in IE8 (8.0.6001.18702IC).  Unfortunately, before I got here the app was written specifically for IE, so no other browser works.  IE9 also does not work.  I'm rewriting for standards compliance now but that will take months (maybe years).

Comment: Does the content for the modal dialog get loaded from an Ajax request?     If so, can you update the answer to show that Ajax code?  And possibly any related CF code?

Comment: Checked the CFServer's exception.log recently?

Comment: Jake, the modal dialog is loaded via a simple JS pop; all the data within is pulled from a server side cfm.  No client side manipulation.

Shawn, the CF log files show nothing when this is reported to have occured.

Thanks.

Comment: Is template caching enabled and/or do you cache the cfm? (some form of caching could explain the irregularity of the issue)

Comment: Jan, thank you for the thoughts.  No active caching is occuring, and trusted cache is not enabled on the box.  I do not believe that caching is occuring at all.  We just received word of another occurence yesterday, but are still unable to internally replicate.

Comment: Have the users take a screen shot when it occurs.  Check to see if the screenshot has any JS error indicators.  Also, if feasible turn on CF request debugging for that one user's IP address, and have them take a screenshot of that information too.

Comment: We have debugging turned on for them.  We'll see what it tells us.

Comment: Can you post the code, I suspect there is an errant # somewhere.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding.  The code for the dialog is over a thousand lines, and there may be proprietary 'shtuff' in there.  So unfortunately I cannot post it.  We're continuing to monitor but now having issues getting CF debug information to appear for the user.  Definitely something strange going on.

Answer (score 0):

I would be sure that you are not caching the ajax pages, also there could be an extra hash somewhere like on a color ##ffffff for example and certain browser standards are allowing it while it crashed and shows # in others, I would also check your markup for any extra  tags, especially closing ones. I have seen this with dialog before. I would love to see code on this if you have it.

Comment: Thank you for the thoughts.  It usually works for this user and they are always using IE on the same computer, so I don't believe it's a standards issue (otherwise it wouldn't be so sporadic).  I'll look at the extra tags, but our app tends to have a ton of them and we've never had a problem before.